# for loop to prepend dir name to file names

Tags: bash, scripting

I know this topic has been already covered (somehow here and also somewhere else) but I beg you indulgence because I'm trying to find my way through the bash scripting art;

I need to sort out the following problem

given that I have:

dir1

- file 1
- file 2
- and so on...

dir2

- file1
- file2
- and so on...

I want to rename files so that

dir1

- dir1_file 1
- dir1_file 2
- dir1_and so on...

dir2

- dir2_file1
- dir2_file2
- dir2_and so on...

so far I've managed to work out the following "exploratory" bash script

```
for d in `ls -d */`
 do
   #echo "$d"
   pre="${d:0:-1}"
   #echo "$pre"
   #cd "${d}"
   pushd "${d}"
    for f in *.jp2
     do
        #echo "${f}"
        echo "${pre}_${f}"
     done
   #cd - 
   #popd    
 done
```

it's seems working (quite) fine except that of the error message

```
line 9: pushd: dir2/: No such file or directory
```

where dir2 is the name of last dir being swept by the for loop...

any help for that? 
what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to `cd` back and forth into directories (`popd` and `pushd` are primarily for interactive use anyway):

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in */*; do
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue

    dir="$( basename "$( dirname "$name" )" )"
    newname="$dir/${dir}_${name##*/}"

    if [ ! -e "$newname" ]; then
        echo mv "$name" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

This iterates over all names in all directories in the current directory. It will skip non-files and extract the directory basename (the name of the directory with no path) into `dir`.  It then constructs a new filename, `$newname`, for the file using `$dir` and the basename portion of the pathname in `$name` (`${name##*/}` may be replaced by `$( basename "$name" )`).

If the new name is not already taken, the file is renamed.

Remove the `echo` to actually rename the files once you have verified that it ought to do the right thing.

---

To perform a set of actions in another directory and then come back, use

```
( cd dir
  action
  action 
  action )
```

The changed directory does not influence the environment outside of the `( ... )`.

---

See also: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I see you mean something like this...

for d in `ls -d */`
 do
   pre="${d:0:-1}"
   (cd "${d}"
   for f in *.jp2
  do
     echo "${pre}_${f}"
  done
   )
done

Comment: I'll carefully study your more efficient code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say “dir2 is the name of last dir being swept by the for loop”,
but it’s actually the *second* and last, isn’t it? 
It’s failing because you have the `popd` commented out. 
At the end of the first loop iteration, you’re still “in” `dir1`,
so your attempt to `pushd dir2` is actually looking for `dir1/dir2`;
i.e., `dir2` within `dir1`.

If you have seven directories, it would fail for the last six.

You raise the concern that
“uncommenting popd exposes to other unwanted aftermaths,
.... i.e., what about the case if a file (not a dir) is present
among the dirs (at the same level) being iterated by for loop”. 
Well,

- That logic is like saying, “If I wear a right shoe in addition to a left shoe,
  that gives me one more thing to aim my gun at,
  so I’m all the more likely to shoot myself in the right foot.” 
  This makes no sense. 
  Doing `pushd` and not following it with `popd` (especially in a loop)
  is much, much more wrong than wearing only one shoe.
- Since you’re using `*/`, you will get only directories.

  - But Kusalananda is right:
    you should use `for d in */` rather than `` for d in `ls -d */`⁠ ``.
- Better yet, you could do something like

  ```
  for d in *
   do
      …
      if [ -d "$d" ]
      then
          pushd "$d"
          for f in *.jp2
           do
              …
           done
          popd    
      fi
   done
  ```

  or

  ```
  for d in *
   do
      …
      if pushd "$d" 2> /dev/null
      then
          for f in *.jp2
           do
              …
           done
          popd    
      fi
   done
  ```

  so you don’t try to treat a non-directory as a directory.

Comment: yes, you are right; let me just say that by uncommenting popd exposes to other unwanted aftermaths, at least I think to understand.... i.e. what about the case if a file (not a dir) is present among the dirs (at the same level) being iterated by for loop...

Comment: both your amended solutions (for not shooting in the right foot!) do not seem to work properly, as far as I understand... i.e. the same problem of treating a non-directory as a directory
I'll stay on the other line...
thanks anyway

Comment: The second version did have an issue of producing many error messages — I have fixed that. Otherwise, they both work for me. If you can clarify what is going wrong, I might be able to help you. For example, are you getting to the `for f in *.jp2` statement when you haven’t `pushd`’d into a subdirectory? Are you doing `popd` when you aren’t `pushd`’d into a subdirectory?